# Why has a beneficial edit on a popular locked question been rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, locked-posts

**This is the edit in question**: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28671100

> Rejection Reason: *This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.*

In my edit summary, I tried to explain explicitly **why** I made an edit instead of adding a new answer: it's the top answer and it will most likely stay there. Given the fact that [people are impatient](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tl%3Bdr), plus the fact that the post is locked and no new answers can be added *and* that the comment sections on the question and the top answer are "polluted" already (to see the most recent comments, you have to click on `Show more comments` and scroll all the way down), I think there's no right-minded reason to reject an edit outlining the new official solution which would clearly benefit experienced and especially new Python programmers.

I believe that, if there was no prominently placed information about the new official solution, most of the readers would think there's only a workaround - and use that instead.

Lastly, I don't think my edit downgrades the answer - as I'm only adding information and still try to **keep it as short as possible**, not erasing its on-point-quality. I attempted to do this by telling about the most important aspects only and linking to another post of mine for a more in-depth summary.

Is my view on this correct or am I mistaken?

Comment: Isn't there another answer that already mention the syntax you wanted to add to the accepted answer?

Comment: No. As I already outlined in my question here "the post is locked" - with the most recent answer being from Feb 2019.

Comment: Doesn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30881320/1426539) answer already mention the `match` syntax for Python > 3.10?

Comment: Ah, indeed. Sorry for having missed that. Anyways, that's not the rejection reason to my edit. And furthermore it's so far down the page that no one looking for a quick solution will find it. This works against my intention to just make people write clean PEP-compliant code.

Comment: The question has 60 answers. Sorting by active, is the first one after the accepted/pinned.

Comment: Generally, that rejection reason is adequate for this type of edit. For this specific case, since the question was answer-locked, an edit to an answer could have been acceptable. But not if the edit simply repeats information already provided in another answer.

Comment: So are we going to think that people ignore the accepted 1600-Upvotes answer and the following 10 ones in favor of clicking a sorting button?

Comment: I understand your points. Regardless, I'm trying to improve upon the Python community by having the users write better code. I'm asking myself if they are going to write better code if the post looks like it does right now. And then I come to the conclusion that they would do better if they found the information without doing a deeper search.

Comment: Just because you don't read other more current answers doesn't mean other people don't. With that said there is a project in the works to create tools to handle outdated content

Answer (score 10):

As a reviewer mostly active in the suggested edits queue, I would like to provide some thoughts on the edit.

Firstly, you suggested an edit on a *highly upvoted accepted* answer, which by itself is a red flag.

Secondly, you linked *to your own* post which, merits aside, can be viewed as *self-promotion*. In combination with the first point, this is a huge red flag.

Thirdly, you cluttered the edit with meta-information ("unfortunately SO didn't allow me to add it to this particular question anymore"), which is something you specify in the reason for the edit, not in the edit itself, as this information is irrelevant to the post.

Fourthly, by using *singular first-person pronouns*, you made it look like the edited-in part and the supplementary answer (see point 2) was written by the OP. By now we are in the territory of "clearly conflicts with author's intent".

Finally, on top of points 2 & 4, you significantly changed a non-community wiki post (despite the Q&A being locked as a community effort, there are still both types of answers), which usually leads to the rejection reason "This edit was intended to address the author of the post" (as reviewers unanimously did).

---

With the above said, the proper conduct would be to either:

1. Wait until you unlock the full edit privilege at 2K and edit the post yourself (option 2 would still be the proper etiquette).
2. Comment on the answer (which you did a while ago) and ask the OP to incorporate the proposed edits.
3. Make your edit on the most suitable community wiki post (CWs are specifically designed for collaboration and have a low rep edit threshold for a reason).
4. Remove meta info from the edit, disclose the attribution of the answer, and reword the edit in a way that does not make it look like the OP wrote what they had not.

In the case of option 4, the edit would likely be rejected too, but you would stand a much better chance.

Comment: The self promotion of another post also signals to me the edit was not really done in good faith at all as suggested above

Comment: @charlietfl - I tend to assume good faith, but this certainly makes the edit a no-go (in the absence of all the other issues it would probably make sense to edit out the promotion part as good-faith editor will not object about it, but there are too many problems with the edit to do that)

Comment: I'll rephrase to allow some benefit of doubt... *"may not have been done in good faith"*. That's what i would conclude in a review cue based on it being a very high traffic heavily voted answer

Comment: @charlietfl - agreed, just meant that for someone who doesn't get the bad faith signal right off, encountering this usually makes me want to hit reject instantly regardless of the intentions unless there are very compelling reasons to spend some time to improve the edit.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the detailed outline. I now understand your thoughts on this.

Comment: @fameman - I wasn't among those who reviewed your edit, so maybe they had their own reasons, but most likely it is one or the combination of the ones outlined above. Anyways, don't get discouraged by the rejection - just take the reasons into account next time (and when you eventually get access to the edit review queues, should you decide to take part, these should help you make weighted decisions easier)

Comment: Good words. It's my intention to improve upon myself - therefore it's good I got this answer as sort of a guideline. Thanks, again.